# Using Math.Round(ReportItems!category.Value,MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) returns incorrect value

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am using

```
=Math.Round(ReportItems!category.Value,MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
```

in a tablix row, which results incorrect value.

`5.48` is rounding to `5`

Instead, I would like to see `5.48` as `6`.

Answer (score 2):

What you are asking for is not [rounding away from zero](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.midpointrounding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), it is [`Ceiling`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.ceiling%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for positive numbers and [`Floor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.floor%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for negative numbers.

Answer (score 1):

`MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero` Is a way of defining how the **midpoint** value is handled.  The midpoint is `X.5`.  So, `4.5` is rounded to `5`, rather than `4`, which is what would happen in the case of `MidpointRounding.ToEven`.  `Round` is completely correct.

If you want to write a function that rounds all non-integer values to the next highest integer then that operation is `Math.Ceiling`, not `Round`.